# I would include a figure with caption ( not image ) in a tabular as a result

Tags: tables, graphics

I tried to create the same design with this code, but the problem is that it integrates an image but not a figure, because I want to include it in the list of figures after, I tried to type begin {figure} but it displays only errors :

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.pdf,.png}
%%Déclarer un nouveau type de colonne personnalisé( en paramétre la largeur du colonne souhaité
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{L{6cm} C{6cm}|}
\rowcolor{lightgray}\multicolumn{2}{|L{13cm}}{Niveaux du reporting IAC BPF }\\
\hline
\includegraphics[height=5cm,width=6cm]{niveauReportingBPF}
&
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{241},leftmargin=0cm]
\item{Niveau national : Total BPF et contribution de chaque DR y compris   la contribution de la gestion de fortune.}
\item{Niveau régional : Total DR et contribution de chaque CBP.}
\item{Niveau local    : Total CBP et contribution de chaque FDC.}
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

and here is the result displayed :
[image]

Comment: `\includegraphics{imageName}\par\captionof{figure}{See a picture, not an image}` (package `capt-of` or `caption` needed).

Comment: If that doesn not help, please provide more information (Minimal Working Example). Showing an image and wanting code is like asking for a recipe by showing a picture of a stew.

Comment: your mwe doesn't work. perhaps are missed some packages. check please.

Comment: @Zarko Now , he his working , Please help me !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

(in real document you had to remove option `demo` at the package `adjustbox`). for caption i used the package `capt-of`, for image positioning the package `adjustbox`, which also provide functionality of package `graphicx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }p{#1}}  % <--- chnged
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }p{#1}} % <--- chnged
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }p{#1}}   % <--- chnged
\usepackage[demo, export]{adjustbox} % <-- instead of the package graphicx
                                     % in real document remove "demo"

\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[htb]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{L{6cm} C{6cm}|}
\rowcolor{lightgray}
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{Niveaux du reporting IACBPF }\\
\hline
\includegraphics[height=5cm,width=6cm,valign=T]{niveauReportingBPF}
\captionof{figure}{Caption text}
&
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin = *,label = \ding{241}]
\item{Niveau national : Total BPF et contribution de chaque DR y compris   la contribution de la gestion de fortune.}
\item{Niveau régional : Total DR et contribution de chaque CBP.}
\item{Niveau local    : Total CBP et contribution de chaque FDC.}
    \end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Zargo , i am using this code but the picture is still black ! help me plz

Comment: do you remove option `demo` from `adjustbox`? ( there is comment which instruct you, that you should do this in your real document).

Comment: I would add a border to my image in table but it show an error , please can you solve it ?

Comment: @YounessGI, test `\fbox{\includegraphics[height=5cm,width=6cm,valign=T]{niveauReportingBPF}}`. is this what you looking for? if it is not, than please ask new question where explain your problem more clear and show, how you try to obtain border around image.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to put captions on non-floating images is to use the proper keys of `adjustbox`.

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
...
\includegraphics[height=5cm,width=6cm,valign=t,captionbelow={Caption text},nofloat=figure]{niveauReportingBPF}
```

alternative:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
...
\adjustimage{height=5cm,width=6cm,valign=t,captionbelow={Caption text},nofloat=figure}{niveauReportingBPF}
```

As you did not provide an minimal working example (MWE) I didn't tested it with your code.

Comment: a two solution gave a error : the first give : "package keyval error" , the second :"undefined control sequence \adjustimage " !!

Comment: @YounessGI, before you complain that solution not works, provide minimal working example, a small complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `end{document}`, that we can test our solution with your code.

Comment: @Zarko , i edited the code ,  can you help me now please ?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer, now the op mwe  is known. please can you extend your answer to mwe? in my tests of your solution i had problems with  aligning of image, the second example throw error `missing item`

Comment: @Zarko: Strange, `\adjustimage{height=5cm,width=6cm,valign=t,captionbelow={Caption text},nofloat=figure}{example-image}` works, but not without `valign`. I will check this further.

Comment: please, inform us about your findings!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to reference the figure in the List of Figures, you can use `\addtocontents{lof}{figure}{description of figure}`. This will add a line with a page reference to your list of figures. Note that you might have to `\protect` the last argument if you use macros in there.

Comment: This does neither give a number to the figure nor does it leave a description of the figure at the position where the figure is included.

Comment: Correct. But that might be just what OP wants in this situation.